# Batch script in DOS, traverse multiple lists pairwise

Tags: batch-file

I have two lists, alpha and beta, with n items each.  They are two variables defined in the batch file itself.

I want a loop that iterates through from both lists, pairwise.

So, I would have access to

```
alpha1 and beta1

then 

alpha2 and beta2

etc...
```

We have looped through one list (alpha), but there is no apparent index to use to index into beta.

We need this to be in DOS batch scripting, not powershell.

Comment: And what have you tried? Where is the problem?

Comment: Do you can show the code and where it fails?

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that your lists are Batch variables with space-separated items like these:

```
set alpha=alpha1 alpha2 alpha3 alpha... alphaN
set beta=beta1 beta2 beta3 beta... betaN
```

If so, then you may process they as you want this way:

```
set i=1
:loop
for /F "tokens=%i%" %%a in ("%alpha%") do set alphaElem=%%a
for /F "tokens=%i%" %%b in ("%beta%") do set betaElem=%%b
if "%alphaElem%" == "" goto endLists
echo Pair %i%- %alphaElem% and %betaElem%
set /A i+=1
goto loop
:endLists
```

A different and faster approach is to first convert the lists into arrays and then directly manipulate the array elements:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%a in (%alpha%) do set /A i+=1 & set alpha[!i!]=%%a
set i=0
for %%b in (%beta%) do set /A i+=1 & set beta[!i!]=%%b
set n=%i%
. . .
for /L %%i in (1,1,%n%) do echo Pair %%i- !alpha[%%i]! and !beta[%%i]!
```